# Proper pratice for DOM Manipulation in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am coming from a Jquery / MVC web developer background, trying to create my first project in Angular 2.

I need to do something simple, I just want a span to turn into a textbox when clicked (and then turn back into a span when the save button is clicked). 
The span/textbox|button will be inside a *ngFor loop

My Component html file looks like this:
inboxmail.component.html

```
<table id="inbox-table" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let mailItem of mail">
            <td class="inbox-table-icon">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox style-2">
                        <span></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="inbox-data-from hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                <div class="pointer" (click)="renameReference($event)" id="{{mailItem.id}}"> <!-- this is the span that is clickable -->
                    <span>
                        {{mailItem.reference}}
                    </span>
                    <span class="collapse">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  />
                        <input type="button"" class="btn btn-success" />
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="inbox-data-message">
                <div>
                    {{mailItem.ocrText}}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="inbox-data-attachment hidden-xs">
                <div>
                    <img src="{{getImgUrl(mailItem.status)}}" alt="{{mailItem.status}}"  />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="inbox-data-date hidden-xs">
                <div>
                    {{mailItem.created | amDateFormat:'LL'}}
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And so far my ts file is:
inboxmail.compontent.ts

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { GetMailService } from '../../../services/get-mail.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Mail } from '../../../model/mail'

@Component({
    selector: 'inboxmail',
    templateUrl: './inboxmail.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./inboxmail.component.css'],
    providers: [GetMailService]

})
export class InboxMailComponent {

    public mail: Mail[];

    constructor(private service: GetMailService) {
        service.getMail()
            .subscribe(mail => { console.log("mail", mail); this.mail = mail; }),
            null,
            () => console.log("complete", this.mail);
    }

    getImgUrl(status): string {
        switch (status){
            case "Stored":
             return "/content/images/icons/store.png";

            case "Shreded":
                return "/content/images/icons/Shred.png";

            case "Forwarded":
                return "/content/images/icons/Forward.png";
        }
        return "";
    }

    renameReference(event): void {
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
        //Jquery here?
        console.log("clicked", event);
    }

}
```

So with jquery it would be fairly simple. I could just make the target in renameReference(event) a jquery object, find the spans and hide/show as necessary on click.

But my 2 questions, is should I (best pratice) be using Jquery inside a angular typescript class? Or should I forget jquery all together and do it a angular 2 way? If the latter how is it done in Angular 2?

And finally, should this work be done inside the component ts, or should I make a attribute directive to handle this?

Comment: I'd recommend trying not to use JQuery if you can avoid it, especially for DOM manipulation, which might happen outside of Angular's awareness. For hiding and showing things you can use either *ngIf (to add and remove from the DOM) or [hidden] (to just hide and show something that remains in the DOM.) You can bind both of those to boolean properties of your component.

Comment: thanks, I can easily hide/show ALL the elements in the loop by making the element [hidden]="isEditMode". But i need to target only the elements within the area clicked (and not all those elements in the table)

Comment: You can introduce a new property in `mailItem` e.g `editMode` which would be a boolean. Then you can toggle that boolean `mailItem.editMode` between edit and "span mode". And I agree with Rob, please avoid jquery :)

Comment: Thanks AJT_82, its so simple. That's what I'll do.